# VPS debian 64 bits put cron to reboot at 7:00 every day

Tags: cron

I have a VPS with debian 64bit. And I would like to set a daily reboot at 7:00

with $ ps aux

**root      1844  0.0  0.1  18832   964 ?        Ss   07:23   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron**

so the cron it's running.

When I logme in to the VPS through sftp, I can see the crontab file in /etc/crontab/.

I edit that crontab file and in the bottom I have introduce

0 7 * * * reboot

save and exit and reboot (to assume the cron) but don't did nothing

than I tried another those command lines and did nothing

0 7 * * * initd 6

0 7 * * * shutdown -r now

please help me to see what I'm missing or what I have to check step by step :(

Comment: Why? This is a very bad idea. If you are having performance issues, fix those instead of covering over the problem with a reboot.

Comment: I just want to found out what it's missing to have cron up and running, cause as soon I figured out what's missing I will put cron doing this instead daily will be monthly.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/crontab requires a user argument. So it should be something like this:

```
0 7 * * *   root    /usr/sbin/shutdown -r now
```

Comment: 0 7 * * * root /usr/sbin/shutdown -r now #didn't work... but I have looked in /usr/sbin/ and I didn't saw no shudtdown file.